# Macro with text variables changing columns

Tags: excel, vba

Macro works great until the position of text changes columns. I'm using "find" textstring, then want to move cursor right and down2, then copy data to another sheet. The macro works great until the text string moves in subsequent spreadsheets.

How do I get the selected range to be variable based on where text string is found?
In example below, how do I get `Range("H7:H180").Select` to be variable?

```
Range("A1").Select
Cells.Find(What:="reg", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Range("H7:H180").Select
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim rngFound as Range

Set wks = Sheets("Sheet1") ' adjust for your sheet name
Set rngFound = wks.Cells.Find(What:="reg", After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not rngFound is Nothing Then rngFound.Offset(2,1).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1") 'adjust the destination to fit what you need
```

No need to select anything. You can work directly with the cells. Also, not sure where in your other sheet you want to copy to, but you can adjust the copy destination as need be.

Comment: Thanks Scott. I am not a coder, so this is over my head. I will try to figure it out.

Comment: Did this code work for you? If you still have issues, feel to free to ask, or post another question if its vastly different than this one.

Comment: No. Unfortunately it did not. Is there a way to send you an sample spreadsheet?

Comment: You can post one to a file sharing drive (ie. - google docs, drop box, etc)